Find the maximum value of $|z|$ if $|z^2+1|=2|z+1|$
Consider the following problem:

Let $z$ be a complex number such that $|z^2+1|=2|z+1|$. Find the maximum value of $|z|$.

The answer is $\sqrt 7$. But I have no idea how to get there. I hope someone can help me.
My first attempt is using triangle inequality, but soon I realized that it was the wrong direction to proceed. I've solved a very similar problem that the initial condition was $|z^2+1|=2|z|$, but the problem I'm asking here seem to be more complicated.
The strategy I often use when dealing with this type of problem is to find the locus of the $z$ point. Proceeded as follows:

Let $M$ be the point representing z on the complex number plane, point $(0,1)$ is A and point $(0,-1)$ is $B$, point $(-1,0)$ is $C$,then the initial condition is equivalent to point M satisfying $MA\cdot MB=MC \cdot AB$. This method often leads me to find that the locus of point $M$ are straight lines or conic sections, for example, $2$ circles have a radius of $\sqrt 2$ with centers at $A$ and $B$ respectively if the initial condition was $|z^2+1|=2|z|$. But this problem doesn't get me to the same result.
The another strategy that I thought of was to use the triangle inequality and obtain an inequality of a quadratic equation of |z|. Since I already knew the final result is $\sqrt 7$, i needed to try to force the inequality into the form $|z^2| \leqslant 7$ or something similar, that is impossible, plus the equality condition of the triangle inequality for complex numbers is often difficult to satisfy, so I know this isn't a right direction to proceed.


You should avoid no clue questions. And include your attempt too, to get a positive response from our side.

Oh, Thanks you. My first attempt is using triangle inequality, but soon i realized It was the wrong direction to proceed

Hi! Ideas that might improve your question and help you avoid down-votes and close-votes: 1. Describe how you tried to apply the triangle inequality (or explain how you concluded that it was the wrong direction). 2. Describe how you solved the similar problem, which may yield clues as to how to proceed.

Ah. Thanks you! My apology to half of MSE's population

Being responsive to comments helps! :-)

@TrongNguyen Maybe you could add some more context on your previous work and application of triangle inequality in order to reopen the question. I see the question was closed and there are $2$ reopening votes at the moment.

@user Thanks for suggesting! I've add some characters.

@TrongNguyen Well done! I've now voted for reopening

A more subtle question, is: Find the minimum value of $|z|$.

@Dan Nice question! Then we can employ the triangle inequality, fortunately the equality condition do occur

@TrongNguyen How did you use the triangle inequality to find the minimum value of $|z|$?

@Dan Employing the triangle inequality we get $2-2|z| \leqslant 2|z+1|=|z^2+1| \leqslant |z|^2+1$ which leads to $ -1+\sqrt2 \leqslant |z| $

Put $z := x + iy$, and square both sides to get
$$|z^2+1|^2 = 4|z+1|^2.$$
Simplifying, this becomes
$$(x^2+y^2)^2 = 2x^2 + 6y^2 + 8x + 3. \tag{1}$$
Now, if we set $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$ (geometrically, this amounts to considering points in the intersection of the curve in $(1)$ with the circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin), we get
$$4x^2-8x + R^4 - 6R^2 - 3 = 0. \tag{2}$$
This quadratic equation should have real roots (otherwise $R > 0$ is so large that it does not intersect the curve $(1)$ anymore.) Thus, the discriminant $\Delta$ of this quadratic equation is $\geqslant 0$. This gives
$$\Delta = 64 - 4\cdot 4 \cdot (R^4 - 6R^2 - 3) \geqslant 0,$$
i.e.,
$$R^4 - 6R^2 - 7 \leqslant 0. \tag{3}$$
On factoring $(3)$, we get
$$(R^2- 7)(R^2 + 1) \leqslant 0.$$
Since $R^2 + 1 \ge 0$, and $R > 0$, we get $$0 < R\leqslant \sqrt{7}.$$
Therefore, $R = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = |z| \leqslant \sqrt{7}$, and it is easy to see that this maximum is attained (put $R = \sqrt{7}$ in $(2)$, find $x$, and then find $y$ such that $(x,y)$ is on the curve.)

I'm adding a picture - the green circle is centered at the origin, and has radius $\sqrt 7$, while the red curve is the one described by $(1)$.


Wow. Thanks you so much! I forgot that we can use the discriminant technique

@TrongNguyen You're welcome - feel free to accept the answer if it resolves your query. Since you are a new contributor, I have added an answer. In the future, please remember that it is necessary to ask questions with more context, including your ideas toward a solution.

It might be helpful to future readers (and possibly the OP as well) if you can motivate why you square both sides on the way to Equation $(1)$.

@BrianTung I just wanted to get rid of the square-root! Seems very natural to square it, since $|z| \ge 0$.

@stoic-santiago Yes sir, i will remember that

I understand why the roots should be real....its cuz $x$ lies on real axis...but I can't understand your argument...can you pls elaborate

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad If you ask specific questions about the parts that are not clear, I am happy to elaborate.

otherwise R>0
is so large that it does not intersect the curve (1)
anymore.)....what does this mean

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Well, think about it. If $R$ is large, then $(2)$ has no real roots, and so there are no points $(x,y)$ on the curve $(1)$ satisfying $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$.

I'm not saying it's not natural, but without saying so, a new reader may not understand why you want to do it (since they won't have tried to do it first, much of the time).

@BrianTung That makes sense, thanks for pointing it out! I am usually reluctant to type things that I consider obvious, but perhaps this is a common tragedy (that we should avoid) in all mathematical literature.

Haha, I think we have Bourbaki and their ilk to thank (?) for that kind of aesthetic.

We have that
$$|z^2+1|=2|z+1| \implies (z^2+1)(\bar z^2+1)=4(z+1)(\bar z +1)$$
which leads to
$$|z|^4-6|z|^2+4\Re^2(z)-8\Re(z)-3=0 \implies |z|^2=3+\sqrt{12-4\Re^2(z)+8\Re(z)}$$
and since $-4\Re^2(z)+8\Re(z)$ has $4$ as global maximum at $\Re(z)=1$, we have
$$|z|^2_{\max}=3+\sqrt{12+4}=7 \implies |z|_{\max}=\sqrt 7$$

Very neat solution! +1

it's really nice!
